# Groovy: Returning slash-escaped string causes exception

Tags: string, groovy

I have a simple script, which runs and works:

```
println testReturn()

String testReturn() {
    def str = /asdf/
    return str
}
```

If I change it to this, however, I see an error when I run it:

```
println testReturn()

String testReturn() {
    return /asdf/
}
```

Error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
test.groovy: 6: unexpected token: / @ line 6, column 12.
       return /asdf/
              ^

1 error
```

Does anyone know why I have to define a slash-escaped string before returning it?

Comment: use instead `return(/asdf/)` - fails for me too with 2.5.6

Comment: That's odd. You can omit the `return` keyword instead of defining a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the `return` statement is treated like other function calls in groovy 2.x and that slashy strings do not work well with paren-less function calls.

An example:

```
println /asdf/   // fails
println(/asdf/)  // works

println testReturn()

String testReturn() {
  /asdf/         //works - implicit return
}

String btestReturn() {
  return /asdf/  // fails
}

String testReturn() {
  return(/asdf/) //works
}
```

in my book this is unexpected behavior and a restriction of the groovy parser.

In groovy 3 (or more specifically in this case, groovy 3.0.0-alpha-3), the parser has been rewritten and the following code:

```
println /asdf/   // fails
println(/asdf/)  // works

println testReturn1()
println testReturn2()
println testReturn3()

String testReturn1() {
  /asdf/         // works
}

String testReturn2() {
  return /asdf/  // works
}

String testReturn3() {
  return(/asdf/) // works
}
```

gives the somewhat more informative error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: println for class: solution
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: println for class: solution
  at solution.run(solution.groovy:1)
```

which tells us that without parens, groovy can not determine if `println` is a property or a method call. Removing that first line makes the above code work under groovy 3.x.